# How to refresh div every 10 seconds automatically and stop when click on button?

Tags: javascript, refresh

I have a button when I click on that a `ul` tag will display block.
I want the data inside that `ul` will automatically refresh after 10 seconds. The data is coming through api which I need to hit.
When clicked on stop button then data will not be refreshed.

```
function dummy(){ 
    setTimeout("checkalerts()",10000); 
} 

function checkalerts() { 
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/messages/get/"+contactid,
      data: { since: since }
    })
      .done(function( msg1 ) {

      var el = $('<li class="message right appeared">
<div class="avatar"><img src="'+url+'/service/getUserImage/'+msg1[i].userID +'/60"/></div>
<div class="text_wrapper">
<div class="text">'+msg1[i].message+'</div></div></li>');
                 $(".chat_window ul").append(el);

    });

    }
```

Comment: So you want to stop the timeout? Then just assign setTimeout to a variable and call 'clearTimeout(variable)' if you want to clear it. Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp.

Comment: Just assign the return value of setTimeout to a variable and use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) when the button is clicked.

Comment: Probably you want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Assign it into variable and clear it after click on button

Comment: yes i want to stop the timer on click and also restart it again if it click on start and it will refersh every 10 sec without clicking anywhere

Comment: how to clear the interval value?

Comment: In such cases it's better to use `setTimout` (IMO). You can re-set the timeOut when the Ajax call was successful. If you use `setInterval` do perform the Ajax call and the call fails, it get's executed (and failing) over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep track of the current `setTimeout`. It returns an ID which can also be cancelled again: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

In your ajax success callback, just set the timeout again and save the ID. 
When you press the stop button, cancel the timeout.

```
// assign to the start button
function dummy() {  
  fetch();
}

// assign to stop button
function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

function fetch() {
// do your ajax stuff here
  output.innerHTML = 'fetched ' + new Date().getSeconds();

  // and in the success callback, reset time timeout
  timeoutId = setTimeout(fetch, 1000);
}

btnStart.addEventListener('click', dummy);
btnStop.addEventListener('click', stop);
```

Working demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oam4v81c/3/)

Comment: clearTImeout is not working for me. When i call the stop function its call the stop function but not clearing the timeoutid value what to do ?